# ArgumentException: JSON CORS data could not be loaded from: (GCP)

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, cors, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I wrote **the CORS settings** to **"cors.json" file** as shown below.

**"cors.json"**:

```json
[
    {
      "origin": ["http://localhost:8000"],
      "method": ["GET"],
      "responseHeader": ["Content-Type"],
      "maxAgeSeconds": 3600,
    }
]
```

Then, run the command below to set **the CORS settings** to **my bucket** as shown below:

```
gsutil cors set cors.json gs://my-bucket
```

But I got this error below:

```
ArgumentException: JSON CORS data could not be loaded from: [
    {
      "origin": ["http://localhost:8000"],
      "method": ["GET"],
      "responseHeader": ["Content-Type"],
      "maxAgeSeconds": 3600,
    }
]
```

Are there any mistakes in **the CORS settings**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove **the trailing comma ","** from **the last element** as shown below.

**"cors.json"**:

```json
[
    {
      "origin": ["http://localhost:8000"],
      "method": ["GET"],
      "responseHeader": ["Content-Type"],
      "maxAgeSeconds": 3600, 
    }                   // ↑ Trailing comma
]
```

So, this is **the CORS settings** without **the trailing comma ","** for **the last element** as shown below.

**"cors.json"**:

```json
[
    {
      "origin": ["http://localhost:8000"],
      "method": ["GET"],
      "responseHeader": ["Content-Type"],
      "maxAgeSeconds": 3600 
    }                   // ↑ No trailing comma
]
```

Then, if running the command below again, you can set **the CORS settings** successfully without any errors:

```
gsutil cors set cors.json gs://my-bucket
```